# BASH script expecting then, when I need else

Tags: bash, if-statement, syntax-error

I need a little help with my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

zenity --list --title="Select Server" --text="Select the server to start" --radiolist \
--column= --column=Server --column=Port \
FALSE "Creative+Survival" 25565 \
FALSE "Tekkit Cheat Survival" 25566 \
FALSE "Flat Tekkit" 25567 \
FALSE "SunnyDale City" 25568 \
FALSE "Doom Dungeon" 25569 \
FALSE "Survival Tekkit" 25570 \
| cat > ~/temp


server=$(cat ~/temp)

if $server="Creative+Survival" then
gnome-terminal -x sh "/home/kulboy121/Servers/Creative and Survival/launch.sh"
end

else
echo wrong answer...
end

rm ~/temp
```

This is a script to launch some Minecraft servers I own. I will eventually add if entries for all the other servers as well.
This is the output when I do not select Creative+Survival:

```
Server Startup - INCOMPLETE.sh: 20: Server Startup - INCOMPLETE.sh: Syntax error: "else" unexpected (expecting "then")
```

And when I do select Creative+Survival, the same thing happens. Sorry if this is a stupid question, this is one of my first bash scripts.

Thank you!

Comment: I've found this to be pretty helpful: [http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-6.html](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-6.html)

Comment: Useless **uses** of cat spotted! `... | cat > ...` is terrible (and funny at the same time...) hey, why not `... | cat | cat | cat | cat | cat | cat | cat | cat | cat > ...` while you're at it? `:-)` purrrrr And `var=$(cat file)` is better written as `var=$(< file)`.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! I had a hard time picking the "best" answer, they were all great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bracket `[` (test) operator is missing. It should be something like this:

```
if [ "$server" = "Creative+Survival" ]
then
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
fi
```

NOTE: the spaces around those brackets are important.
The square brackets around the conditional test are actually a synonym for the `test` operator.
So the above is equivalent to:

```
if test "$server" = "Creative+Survival"
then
   echo "true"
else
   echo "false"
fi
```

But everyone uses the brackets; I rarely see scripts that use the `test` keyword.

Also allowed in the bash shell (although this is not as portable because it is not a POSIX standard) is to use double brackets:

```
if [[ "$server" = "Creative+Survival" ]]
then
```

Here's a link to page that describes the differences between `[`, `[[`, and `test`: 
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031

---

**Update**

**Q:** This seems to work, but it spits out an error code if I select anything other then "Creative+Survival". Is this supposed to happen?

**A:** It's not at all clear what error code is being spit out by what component. I expect you want to check for each possible selection. You can do that with an `elif`, or with a `case`.

```
if [ "$server" = "Creative+Survival" ]
then
    echo "Creative and Survival"
elif [ "$server" = "Tekkit Cheat Survival" ]
then
    echo "Tekkit Cheat Survival"
elif [ "$server" = "Flat Tekkit" ]
then
    echo "Flat Tekkit"
else
    echo "no action for specified server"
fi


case "$server" in
    'Creative+Survival')
        echo "Creative and Survival"
        ;;
    'Tekkit Cheat Survival')
        echo "Tekkit Cheat Survival"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "no action found for server $server"
        ;;
esac
```

(NOTE: the indentation is to improve readability only; bash cares about the newlines, not the leading spaces.)

Comment: This seems to work, but it spits out an error code if I select anything other then "Creative+Survival". Is this supposed to happen?

Comment: I expect you'd want to use a series of `elif` to check other conditions, or use a `case` statement to check multiple conditions.  It's not at all clear (to me) what error code is being spit out by which component in your script.

Comment: You need double-quotes around $server (i.e. `if [ "$server" = "Creative+Survival" ]` etc), or things will get very confused if it contains spaces.

Comment: @Gordon Davisson: excellent point. I would have caught that if I tested it, which is why I should test.

Answer (score 3):

In bash you have to remember that `then` must be in a new line. Unfortunately your whole `if` statement is not correct. The proper string comparison looks something like that:

```
 if [[ "$server" = "pattern" ]]; then
       # do something
 else
       # do something else
 fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Your if-statement is incorrect.

- The condition goes within brackets: `[[...]]`
- `then` goes on a new line
- The statement ends with `fi` not `end`

There is also a [Useless Use of `cat`](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html) which I have fixed.

Try this:

```
server=$(zenity --list --title="Select Server" --text="Select the server to start" --radiolist \
--column= --column=Server --column=Port \
FALSE "Creative+Survival" 25565 \
FALSE "Tekkit Cheat Survival" 25566 \
FALSE "Flat Tekkit" 25567 \
FALSE "SunnyDale City" 25568 \
FALSE "Doom Dungeon" 25569 \
FALSE "Survival Tekkit" 25570)
if [[ $server == "Creative+Survival" ]]
then
    gnome-terminal -x sh "/home/kulboy121/Servers/Creative and Survival/launch.sh"
else
    echo wrong answer...
fi
```

Comment: This is definitely the best answer, where all the asker's mistakes are corrected! Thanks dogbane, `+1`.

Answer (score 1):

Others have answered the syntax problems.

Going forward, the `case` statement will serve you well:

```
server=$(...)
case $server in 
  "Creative+Survival")
    gnome-terminal -x sh "/home/kulboy121/Servers/Creative and Survival/launch.sh"
    ;;
  "Tekkit Cheat Survival")
    # do something
    ;;
  "Flat Tekkit")
    # do something
    ;;
  "SunnyDale City")
    # do something
    ;;
  "Doom Dungeon")
    # do something
    ;;
  "Survival Tekkit")
    # do something
    ;;
  *)
    echo wrong answer
    ;;
esac
```

Additionally, rather than use zenity, use bash's `select` statement. Assuming you have bash v4

```
declare -A port
port["Creative+Survival"]=25565
port["Tekkit Cheat Survival"]=25566
port["Flat Tekkit"]=25567
port["SunnyDale City"]=25568
port["Doom Dungeon"]=25569
port["Survival Tekkit"]=25570

PS3="Select server: "
select server in "${!port[@]}"; do
    if [[ -n $server ]]; then
        # user has given a valid selection
        echo do something with "$server" and "${port[$server]}"
        break
    fi
done
```