# shell script issue with positional arguments and if else

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to write a script that will accept positional arguments (command-line arguments) that specify a mathematical operation (add, sub, mult, div, mod) and two values. The script is supposed to get this input, compute the result, and display the answer. I'm not sure where I went wrong because when I try to run my script, this is what I get

> ```
> ./trial.sh mod 15 10
> ./trial.sh: 6:        if [[ mod == add ]] then: not found
> Result:  25
> ./trial.sh: 9:        elif [[ mod == sub ]] then: not found
> Result:  5
> ./trial.sh: 12:        elif [[ mod == mult ]] then: not found
> Result:  150
> ./trial.sh: 15:        elif [[ mod == div ]] then: not found
> Result:  1
> ./trial.sh: 18:        elif [[ mod == mod ]] then: not found
> Result:  5
> ./trial.sh: 21:        else: not found
> error
> ./trial.sh: 23: fi: not found
> ```

This is the code I used that presented that result

```
#!/bin/bash
        a=$1
        b=$2
        c=$3
        result=0        
"       if [[ $a == add ]] then"
           result=$((b + c))
           echo "Result: " $result
"       elif [[ $a == sub ]] then"
           result=$((b - c))
           echo "Result: " $result
"       elif [[ $a == mult ]] then"
           result=$((b * c))
           echo "Result: " $result
"       elif [[ $a == div ]] then"
           result=$((b / c))
           echo "Result: " $result
"       elif [[ $a == mod ]] then"
           result=$((b % c))
           echo "Result: " $result
"       else"
           echo "error"
        "fi"
```

Comment: If you look up e.g. [How do I compare two string variables in an 'if' statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277665/how-do-i-compare-two-string-variables-in-an-if-statement-in-bash) you'll see that none of them use quotes around `"       if [[ $a == add ]] then"`. You shouldn't either.

Comment: the compiler I used wouldn't run without it

Comment: Syntax error: "elif" unexpected (expecting "then") is what shows up when I remove the ""

Comment: What make & model is that?

Comment: Great. If you Google that error you get [BASH script expecting then, when I need else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073294/bash-script-expecting-then-when-i-need-else), or if you run it through [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) you get "SC1010: Use semicolon or linefeed before 'then'".

Comment: Ubuntu, a linux operating system

Comment: Remove the quotes around `if`s

Comment: it returns unexpected ending without quotes around if

Comment: @Toaster1 : May I suggest that you first fix the syntax problems, verify it on ShellCheck, and then ask a new question with a syntactically clean script, where you describe how you invoke your script, what result you get and what result you would expect. From your comments, you can't expect much helpful responses.

Comment: @Toaster1 : Also remove the _bash_ tag, since there is no bash involved in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sample code is incorrect in several ways. You wrapped some of your statements in double-quotes to make the errors stop, but this is a bit like taking the engine out of a car because it's making a weird noise.

Here are three things you can do immediately to make your code work:

1. take away the double-quotes so that your code is code statements again and not strings. If you want to temporarily disable some shell code, put `#` before it to comment it out, e.g.,

```
# don't wrap broken code in double-quotes:
"if[x= 1]] then rm -rf /"
# instead, comment it out, like this:
# if[x= 1]] then rm -rf /
```

3. in bash if...then, a newline or semicolon is required before `then` , e.g.,

```
if [[ $a == 1 ]] then   # wrong

if [[ $a == 1 ]]; then  # ok

if [[ $a == 1 ]]        # also ok
then
```

3. change `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash` because many variants of `sh` don't support double-bracket `[[` tests.

Comment: This helped. Thank you.